# Additional textboxes on click of an element

Tags: forms, popup, winforms

In my application you can map certain fields by drag and drop. As soon as they are mapped I want them to be clickable to show textboxes into which the user can write additional information for the mapped field.

Where would be the correct place to make that textboxes appear? 
I'm using windows forms. I would prefer to not waste space for this, so I'd prefer a popup or something like this. Currently my form consists of two columns (one to drag the element from and one with rows to drop them on) which completely fill out the form.

Are there other options than making my form larger or putting the information into a popup? If not, should i use an 'inline popup' or a separate form?

Comment: Do you have any screenshots / wireframes what can give us an idea of what this looks like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A example of a modal form window:

https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/dialog/modal-form.html

This sounds like what you are asking about.  Its a very common practice to get the count of on-screen elements down, so if you can do this, it should help keep your interface minimal.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Would you also recommend this in a windows forms application? It seems unconventional

Comment: I am unsure the limitations of windows forms.  I think a drop down box containing a text field will fit in with other windows products, or you could take inspiration from web interfaces like in my answer and be creative.